# Remove "page" from pagination URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wordpress

I have problem with changing pagination URL in Wordpress. I know that universal solution for this is to changing Wordpress core files, but I need this solution only for one category. Maybe for only one category this can be done by htaccess?

There is now URL like this:
http://mysite.com/categoryname/**page**/3

and I want change it to this:
http://mysite.com/categoryname/3

Thanks for any response

Answer (score 3):

You need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` to ensure that you're matching against the actual request and not an internally rewritten URI:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /categoryname/page/([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /categoryname/%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/categoryname/([0-9]+)$ /categoryname/page/$1 [L]
```

These have to be before the wordpress rules.

Comment: Great feature, didn't knew it !

Comment: Unfortunately this not working in Wordpress. Returning "Page Not Found"

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should use this htaccess rule :

```
RewriteRule ^categoryname/page/([0-9]+)$ /categoryname/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^categoryname/([0-9]+)$ /categoryname/page/$1 [L]
```

- The first rule change your old url `categoryname/page/3` into `categoryname/3`.
- The second rule is an invisible redirection from `categoryname/3` to `categoryname/page/3`.

Then you can use both `categoryname/page/3` and `categoryname/3` in your code, this will always show the short version in url.

Notice that there could have some issues with other similar url (make sure that you'll never user `categoryname/3` somewhere else)

**EDIT**

Inifinite loop... how could I miss it !

The way to avoid this loop will be to find the "final url" for `category/page/3` (for example : `index.php?category_name=categoryname&page=3`), and use it in your second rule :

```
RewriteRule ^categoryname/page/([0-9]+)$ /categoryname/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^categoryname/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?category_name=categoryname&page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!

When I added both rules and go to http://mysite/categoryname/3 I have got error about incorrect redirections (infinite loop of redirections). When I removed first rule I have got Error 404 "Not Found".

Comment: Damn... theory and practice ! You can remove the first rule, this will allow you to use `categoryname/3`, but old urls will still be here. See my edit.

Comment: Still not found but in page title at the end I found "Page 3", so page is recognized. I checked that index.php?category_name=categoryname&page=3 redirecting to categoryname/?page=3

Comment: Facing the exact issue. Have you fixed this?@user1613555