# how can I change the format of a pagination URL on a WordPress blog page?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, permalinks

**The current default URL structure is:**

`www.example.com/page/2`

`www.example.com/page/3`

**I want to change it to:**

`www.example.com/2`

`www.example.com/3`

I want to remove "page/". how can I do that?

I tried to add redirection rules on `.htacces` but it doesn't work. this is the code I am using for the pagination links.

```
 echo paginate_links( array(

            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

            'format' => '?paged=%#%',

            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

            'total' => $custom_query->max_num_pages,

            'prev_text'          => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>'),

            'next_text'          => __('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'),

        ) );
```

Comment: what did you add to ```.htaccess``` ?

Comment: i added these lines

Comment: RewriteRule ^nyheter/page/([0-9]+)$ /nyheter/$1 [L,R=301]                         
 RewriteRule ^nyheter/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?category_name=nyheter&page=$1 [L]

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include this extra information. Please avoid adding additional information as a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050524/remove-page-from-pagination-url